# Matlab - plot's legend is displaying incorrect colours

Tags: matlab

```
scatter(index, listm, 'b', 'O');
hold on
scatter(index, listb, 'r', '.');
hold on
plot(index, listerror);
legend('m values', 'b values', 'relative mean square error');
```

It shows the error as being a separate colour, but both of the scatters are red. One of them shows as blue.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a simple typo on your part. In any case it's unclear what you're asking for and as far as the posted example goes, everything is working as expected.

Your example is interpreted as such - `listm` data will display as blue, `listb` as red, and `listerror` as blue since it is the first plot for which you have not defined a color and are using `hold on`. This is different than if you were to use `hold all` which will use red instead of blue to color `listerror` since you've already used blue.

Also, you do not need to keep calling `hold on/all` unless you've called `hold off` on that particular figure.